# Next step after PromptAsync is not called

Tags: botframework

I have this simple dialog, with 2 simple waterfall steps.
The user sees "How may I help you today?" and when it answers, nothing happens. I can't get Validate to work.

Am I missing something? I'm using SDK 4.1.5.

```
public ComplaintsDialog() : base(nameof(ComplaintsDialog))
{
    var steps = new WaterfallStep[]
    {
        Ask,
        Validate
    };

    AddDialog(new WaterfallDialog("flow", steps));
    AddDialog(new TextPrompt("asking"));
}

private static async Task<DialogTurnResult> Ask(WaterfallStepContext sc, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    return await sc.PromptAsync("asking", new PromptOptions { Prompt = new Activity { Text = "How may I help you today?", Type= ActivityTypes.Message}  }, cancellationToken);
}

private static async Task<DialogTurnResult> Validate(WaterfallStepContext sc, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    var answer = sc.Result;
    await sc.Context.SendActivityAsync(answer.ToString());
    return await sc.EndDialogAsync();
}
```

}

**UPDATE**
I tried to simplify the code, and this is how I currently call ComplaintsDialog directly from the main bot.
It looks like the stack is always empty when it gets to **await dc.ContinueDialogAsync();**, so it's going into a loop and start ComplaintsDialog over and over again

```
public async Task OnTurnAsync(ITurnContext turnContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            // Create dialog context.
            var dc = await _dialogs.CreateContextAsync(turnContext);

            switch (turnContext.Activity.Type)
            {
                case ActivityTypes.Message:

                    // Continue outstanding dialogs.
                    await dc.ContinueDialogAsync();

                    // Begin main dialog if no outstanding dialogs/ no one responded.
                    if (!dc.Context.Responded)
                    {
                        await dc.BeginDialogAsync(nameof(ComplaintsDialog));
                    }

                    break;

                case ActivityTypes.ConversationUpdate:
                    if (dc.Context.Activity.MembersAdded != null && dc.Context.Activity.MembersAdded.Any())
                    {
                        foreach (var newMember in dc.Context.Activity.MembersAdded)
                        {
                            if (newMember.Id != dc.Context.Activity.Recipient.Id)
                            {
                                await dc.BeginDialogAsync(nameof(WelcomeDialog));
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    break;                    
            }          
        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code example you provided looks like it should be working so the problem is probably elsewhere.

My guess is that you are starting the ComplaintsDialog inside of a WaterfallStep (from another dialog) so make sure that you are calling the BeginDialogAsync method like this:

`return await stepContext.BeginDialogAsync(nameof(ComplaintsDialog));`

instead of:

`await stepContext.BeginDialogAsync(nameof(ComplaintsDialog));`

If this is not the error probably more information is necessary

**Update**

Your problem is on the OnTurnAsync method. You're not saving the new turn into the conversation state. The Message case on your switch should look like this:

```
case ActivityTypes.Message:

   if (dc.ActiveDialog == null)
   {
      await dc.BeginDialogAsync(nameof(ComplaintsDialog), cancellationToken);
   }
   else
   {
      await dc.ContinueDialogAsync(cancellationToken);
   }

   await _accessors.ConversationState.SaveChangesAsync(turnContext);

   break;
```

And your constructor:

```
private readonly MyBotAccessors _accessors;
public MyBot(MyBotAccessors accessors, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
{

   ...       

   _accessors = accessors ?? throw new System.ArgumentNullException(nameof(accessors));

   ...

 }
```

[SaveChangesAsync documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.bot.builder.botstate.savechangesasync?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev15.query%3FappId%3DDev15IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(Microsoft.Bot.Builder.BotState.SaveChangesAsync);k(DevLang-csharp)%26rd%3Dtrue&view=botbuilder-dotnet-stable)

Comment: Thanks, Andre! Unfortunately, this didn't help. I added some more information to my original question. Any other ideas?

Comment: @Shimix - I just updated the answer according to the new information you provided. Hope it helps

Comment: Thank you @Andre. Completely missed that.